# A namespace cannot directly contain members in AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, build

I have the file `AssemblyInfo.cs` like below. I would like to define a string for the AssemblyVersion:

```
string version = "1.2.0.0";
```

but I get an error saying:

> A namespace cannot directly contain members

How do I do this?

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible  to COM components
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("24f53cr8-552b-40d3-cds1-13e310ds6c3f")]

[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("1/10/2013")]

#if (DEVELOPMENT)
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("ShellDev")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("DEVELOPMENT")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MMD Smart Client - Development Version")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.0.0")]
#endif

#if (RELEASE)
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Shell")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MMD Smart Client")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.0.0")]
#endif
```

Comment: That AssemblyVersion seems fine. Are you sure that error is referring to your AssemblyInfo.cs file?  Does the error go away if you revert the AssemblyVersion?

Comment: You may want to consider why your version number is conditional. Why not take it out of the `#if`s and only declare it once. I'd suggest that the product name and title should also not vary just due to the build configuration, after all, that's what the `AssemblyConfiguration` attribute is there for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no global variables in C#. Put the string in a static class.

```
internal static class Version
{
   public const string VersionString = "1.2.0.0"; 
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion(Version.VersionString)]
```

Comment: Thanks.   Note that the internal class must be after the [assembly...] statements.

Comment: Perhaps `public readonly string ...` is better? I've read that if what you're building will be used in other programs, and you use const, the variable will be inlined and you'll need to rebuild. Whereas if you're using readonly, the variable will not be inlined and actual info will be gotten at runtime.

Comment: Attribute arguments must be constant expressions, so `readonly` doesn't work. It will give you a compiler error.